# Update statement with "case syntax" is unable to update a specific column in temp table

Tags: ssrs, sql-server-2000, reporting

With reviewing a stored procedure for a current SSRS migration. I noticed the case syntax listed below for the temp table (#tempShip) is not taking affect for the column "ord_status" in the temp table. The stored procedure that collects data for the temp table is rather massive so I will refrain from posting. But I believe with the code provided for the update it may do some justification.

Questions:

1. Can you utilize a case statement on a temp table as an update?
2. Is there another method I should try besides the case statement? (I don't think using a subquery with "IF" or "WHERE EXISTS with a select statement" would aid in this)

Notes:

***Stored procedure executes without any errors and temp table is populated with data as expected (But update with case statement does not have expected results)

***With doing a simple case statement as seen below the translation occurs fine

Basic query to test case translation of ord_status data in temp table. Output is correct

```
select ord_status,
 CASE
     WHEN RTRIM([ord_status]) = 'N' THEN 'New'
     WHEN RTRIM([ord_status]) = 'Q' THEN 'Printed'
     WHEN RTRIM([ord_status]) = 'P' THEN 'Picked'
     ELSE ''
 END
 from #tempShip
```

***End of stored procedure where temp table is being updated

```
UPDATE  [#tempShip] SET
        [#tempShip].[DUP] = 1,
        [#tempShip].[ord_status] = 
           CASE
                 WHEN RTRIM([ord_status]) = 'N' THEN 'New'
                 WHEN RTRIM([ord_status]) = 'Q' THEN 'Printed'
                 WHEN RTRIM([ord_status]) = 'P' THEN 'Picked'
                 ELSE ''
           END

        FROM #tempShip
         INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT X.order_N_ext, COUNT(X.order_N_ext) AS dup
        FROM #tempShip AS X
        GROUP BY X.order_N_ext
    ) AS Y
         ON #tempShip.order_N_ext = Y.order_N_ext
    WHERE Y.dup > 1;
    ----- -- mbs 3/30/2017  #22844 - add parameter @ship_type 
    SELECT * FROM #tempShip 
    WHERE ship_type LIKE @ship_type 
    -------<<<


END
DROP TABLE #tempShip
```

**order_N_ext

```
SELECT O.order_no
    , O.ext
    , CONVERT(varchar(20), O.order_no) + ' - ' + CONVERT(varchar(2), O.ext) 
AS 'order_N_ext'
```

Data Example:

```
Ord_Num  BD order_N_ext Loc     Cust        Ship_date                      Ord_Status
1252868  1  1252868 - 1 RAS HQ  21115   2017-04-19 00:00:00.000 2570.63    P       
1253995  1  1253995 - 1 RAS HQ  11471   2017-04-19 00:00:00.000 1270.45    Q       
1254526  0  1254526 - 0 RAS HQ  24104   2017-04-19 00:00:00.000 2214.67    P
```

Comment: @RDFozz I updated some sample data from when the results are returned. And for the temp table definition is there a way to extract that via  code? I found the table in system databases>>>temp tables but I can't view the definition.

Comment: Thanks @RDFozz I will follow up with the Internal DBA team. The column "order_N_ext"  is listed in the post for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution: (The update statements had to be rearranged so they executed on there own.)

```
UPDATE  [#tempShip] SET  [ord_status] = CASE
                WHEN RTRIM([ord_status]) = 'N' THEN 'New'
                WHEN RTRIM([ord_status]) = 'Q' THEN 'Printed'
                WHEN RTRIM([ord_status]) = 'P' THEN 'Picked'
                ELSE ''
                END

UPDATE                 [#tempShip] SET           [#tempShip].[DUP] = 1
FROM #tempShip
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT X.order_N_ext, COUNT(X.order_N_ext) AS dup
FROM #tempShip AS X
GROUP BY X.order_N_ext
) AS Y
ON #tempShip.order_N_ext = Y.order_N_ext
WHERE Y.dup > 1;
    ----- -- mbs 3/30/2017  #22844 - add parameter @ship_type 
    SELECT * FROM #tempShip 
    WHERE ship_type LIKE @ship_type 
    -------<<<
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your numbered questions:

1. Yes, you can use a `CASE` statement when updating a row.
2. I do believe a CASE statement is what you need.

Based on the original code in the question, you are:

- Updating #tempship (where there are at least two rows with the same `order_n_ext` value);
- Selecting records from #tempship based on `ship_type`; and
- dropping `#tempship`.

If there doesn't happen to be two rows with the same `order_n_ext`, or if such rows do exist but don't have the `ship_type` you're `SELECT`ing out of the temp table, then the `UPDATE` statement would work perfectly, but you wouldn't see it.

NOTE:  From your answer, what you ultimately figured out was that you had two different `UPDATE` statements that had been merged into one:

- Update `ord_status` in all rows of `#tempship` to show full words instead of one letter abbreviations; and
- Update the `dup` column to `1` for all rows in `#tempship` where the `order_N_ext` appears in more than on row.

the merge resulted in only duplicate rows having their `ord_status` values updated.

Your solution, splitting the `UPDATE` into two separate statements, is almost certainly the clearest solution. However, it would be possible to do this with one `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE t
   SET [ord_status] = CASE
                        WHEN RTRIM([ord_status]) = 'N' THEN 'New'
                        WHEN RTRIM([ord_status]) = 'Q' THEN 'Printed'
                        WHEN RTRIM([ord_status]) = 'P' THEN 'Picked'
                        ELSE ''
                      END
      ,[dup] = CASE WHEN d.rowCount > 1 THEN 1 ELSE t.dup END
  FROM #tempship t
         LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT order_N_ext, COUNT(*) as rowCount
                            FROM #tempship
                           GROUP BY order_N_ext
                         ) d
```

This will set `#tempship.dup` to `1` where there are 2 or more rows in `#tempship` with this row's `order_n_ext`, and will leave it set to whatever it already was if there's only 1 row.

(Answer added to consolidate info from my comments).

Comment: Much Appreciated,